# Cannot import Angular MockBackend with production build

Tags: angular, testing, mocking

I have implemented a mock backend in my Angular application. This mock backend is used in the end to end tests.

I use a factory to create either an actual http backend service or the mock backend service. Basically it checks if this is a production build and if so it will return a http backend service and otherwise a mock backend service.

Simplified this factory function looks like this:

```
import {
    RequestMethod,
    Http,
    XHRBackend,
    BaseRequestOptions,
    RequestOptions,
    Response,
    ResponseOptions
} from "@angular/http";

import { MockBackend, MockConnection } from "@angular/http/testing";

function backendFactory(mockBackend: MockBackend,
        options: BaseRequestOptions,
        realBackend: XHRBackend) {
    if(!useMockBackend) {
        console.log("Configuring real HTTP backend...");
        return new Http(realBackend, options);
    }

    console.log("Configuring mock HTTP backend...");

    // Listen to incoming requests and send mock data

    return new Http(mockBackend, options);
}
```

When I run this code in a production build I get the following error: `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "@angular/http/testing/src/mock_backend"`

I'm guessing Angular will remove some modules in a production build to decrease the web/app size. However I was not able to find more information about this process. Does anyone know if this can be disabled?

Environment:

- Angular 4.0.0
- Ionic 2.2.2
- Lubuntu 14.04
- Node 6.9.0

Comment: As the error says, mockbackend isn't a module and so cannot be in the import area. You can provide a mockbackend in the providers part. Although I'm not 100% clear what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try upgrade your angular version into 4.1.2. this issue fixed in the angular > 4.1.2.

more info
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15521#issuecomment-290118657

Comment: Just tested and this solved my problem. Thanks for the help!